# CVPixelBuffer – How to capture every THIRD frame out of 60 fps?

Tags: swift, machine-learning, augmented-reality, arkit, apple-vision

I need only 20 frames out of 60 frames per second for processing (`CVPixelBuffer`).

**How to capture every third ARFrame in ARKit session**? I need approximately 20 fps for capture (I understand there may be a drop frame).

Here's a code's snippet:

```
func updateCoreML() {

    let pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer? = (sceneView.session.currentFrame?.capturedImage)

    if pixelBuffer == nil { return }
    let ciImage = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer!)
    let imageRequestHandler = VNImageRequestHandler(ciImage: ciImage, options: [:])

    do {
        try imageRequestHandler.perform(self.visionRequests)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way known to me is to use `RxARKit` and apply `.throttle()` operator to `session.rx.didUpdateFrame`. I believe it is not prudent to skip every so many events because frame rate is not guaranteed to be 60fps at all times, so it is best to use `.throttle()` to get a frame at most every so many milliseconds, no matter what the actual framerate is. You can plug the result of it into `RxVision`, which will take care that that very frame will be used by `CoreML`.

```swift
import RxSwift
import RxARKit
import RxVision


let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
let mlRequest: RxVNCoreMLRequest<CVPixelBuffer> = VNCoreMLRequest.rx.request(model: model, imageCropAndScaleOption: .scaleFit)

mlRequest
    .observable
    .subscribe { [unowned self] (event) in
        switch event {
            case .next(let completion):       
                let cvPixelBuffer = completion.value
                if let result = completion.request.results?[0] as? VNClassificationObservation {
                    os_log("results: %@", type: .debug, result.identifier)
                }
            default:
                break
        }
    }
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)

session
    .rx
    .didUpdateFrame
    .throttle(1/20)
    .subscribe { event in
        switch event {
        case .next(let didUpdateFrame):
        let frame: ARFrame = didUpdateFrame.frame        
        let imageRequestHandler = VNImageRequestHandler(cvPixelBuffer: frame.capturedImage, orientation: .up, options: requestOptions)
        do {
            try imageRequestHandler.rx.perform([mlRequest], with: frame.capturedImage) } catch {
            print(error)
        }            
        break
        default:
            break
        }
    }
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Comment: It is all Carthage, not pods.

Comment: I am using RxVision in my app that is published on AppStore, probably RxARKit is no problem either.

Comment: Added a snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You can either set custom frame rate, so you will get only 20 frames, or you can receive all frames but use only every third frame by taking a flag variable and incrementing it.

```
  func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
       totalFrameCount += 1
       if totalFrameCount % 3 != 0{ return }
}
```

or you can set custom frame rate by extending AVCaptureDevice

```
 lockForConfiguration()
 activeVideoMinFrameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 20)
 activeVideoMaxFrameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 20)
 unlockForConfiguration()
```

Comment: Tahir, thanks for you answer. But this question is exceptionally about ARKit, not AVFoundation. I know what AVFoundation can do and what way.